# Can Aws Managed AD upgrade from Standard to Enterprise easily?

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory

Does anyone know if you can easily migrate from AWS Managed AD Standard Edition to the Enterprise Edition? It seems like this would be a logical option as standard is restricted to 30,000 objects, but I can't find confirmation anywhere on Amazon's sites. (Or elsewhere)

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You will probably have more success asking this somewhere else.

Comment: @GabrielLuci - can you suggest a more appropriate place to ask? (ServerFault seemed like my next best bet)

Comment: Either ServerFault, or ask AWS support directly (if you can).

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems like I am asking in the wrong forum, I have moved to here: https://serverfault.com/questions/981720/can-aws-managed-ad-migrate-from-standard-edition-to-enterprise

Answer (score 0):

The Process can only be done by an AWS Support Engineer if you have access Developer Support plan or higher.

Submit a request through the support portal and they should assist with that.

Before considering upgrading the AWS Managed AD to Enterprise Edition, there will be some irreversible changes once the Managed AD is migrated from Standard to Enterprise.